# Remove duplicate rows but retain data in three columns using Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I will be importing an Excel 2007 file into Access 2007, but before I do that, I must massage the Excel file, as follows:

1.) Remove duplicate rows associated with numeric data in column A.

2.) I need to retain the data in three columns (columns I, P and Q), and combine that alpha numeric data, semi-colon separated, in the retained rows cells of columns I, P and Q.

3.) If any data in columns I, P and Q from the duplicate rows already exists, then do not retain *that* duplicated data

**From This...**
[image]

**To This...**
[image]

I'd be eternally grateful for assistance here. Kinda got pulled into this "mini-project" because I knew what Excel and Access were. Nice. :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  As many new member mistakenly think, stack overflow is not a code for me site.  If you have existing code stack overflow will help with specific problems in that code.  Also it is best that your data be represented directly in the Original post so that we may copy and paste instead of retyping your sample to test.

Comment: As Scott said, this is not a "code for me" site. But for a start, I would scan all rows and check if `Worksheets("data").cells(i+1,1)==Worksheets("data").cells(i,1)`. If true, I would write the concatenated data in a new sheet: `Worksheets("Results").cells(k,9)=Worksheets("data").cells(i+1,9) & Worksheets("data").cells(i,9)`. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829859/repeat-cell-from-year-to-year-in-new-columns-excel/36830023#36830023) for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hoping to deserve that eternal gratitude...

open your worksheet with data, press ALT+F11 to launch the IDE and click Insert->Module. this will add a "Module" in your VBA "Project"

in the "Project Manager Window" (click View-> "Project Manager Window" to possibly show it) double click over the "Module1" node to open the module code pane and place this code in it

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDupesAndRetainData()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim nDupes As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data") '<~~ change sheet name as per your needs
        With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<~~ data are in columns A to P and start from row 1 (headers)

            .Sort key1:=.Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes '<~~ sort rows by "Order"
            For Each cell In .Offset(1).Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<~~ loop through each cell in columns A containing values
                nDupes = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(1), cell.Value) - 1 '<~~ count duplicates
                If nDupes > 0 Then '<~~ if there are any ...
                    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cell.Value '<~~ ...filter data by "order" as current cell content -> only rows with same current cell content will be displayed...

                    With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ''<~~ ...consider only visible cells of data range, skipping headers row...
                        Intersect(cell.EntireRow, .Columns("I")).Value = Join(Application.Transpose(Intersect(.Cells, .Columns("I").EntireColumn)), ";") ' ...concatenate "Resource" field...
                        Intersect(cell.EntireRow, .Columns("P")).Value = Join(Application.Transpose(Intersect(.Cells, .Columns("P").EntireColumn)), ";") ' ...concatenate "Special" field...
                        Intersect(cell.EntireRow, .Columns("Q")).Value = Join(Application.Transpose(Intersect(.Cells, .Columns("Q").EntireColumn)), ";") ' ...concatenate "Notes" field...
                        cell.Offset(1).Resize(nDupes).EntireRow.Delete '<~~ delete duplicate rows
                    End With

                    .AutoFilter '<~~ remove filters
                End If
            Next cell

        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

back to Excel UI, press Alt+F8 to have the Macro dialog box pop out

select "RemoveDupesAndRetainData" in the combobox and then press the "Execute" button

watch what happens... in case of errors you can press "Debug" button in the error message box to throw you in the VBA editor right at the line causing the error

another way of running the macro is the following:

in the VBA IDE (ALT+F11 from Excel UI) module code pane (double click on the wanted Module node in the Project Manager Window ) place the mouse cursor in any point between `Sub RemoveDupesAndRetainData` and `End Sub` statements and press F8 to have your macro start with its first line yellow shaded

now press F8 to step through each code line that will be executed and that will yellow shaded as well

at every step you can query every variable value by hovering the mouse over any of its occurrence within the code or by typing `? variable_name` in the *Immediate Window* (that you can visualize by clicking "Ctrl+G" or selecting View->Immediate Window)

placing the mouse cursor within any significative code "word" and pressing "F1" will launch the relevant help topic to learn about that specific object. each topic will have hyperlinks to dig into and get more corresponding info

of course the web is another invaluable knowledge source where to find almost everything you currently need, with dozens of blogs specific to Excel and VBA

I think what above will get you started and, more important, going on

it's a long way but everybody here who's helping coding fellows started like that, and never reached the end of it

Answer (score 0):

Additional variant from my side:

```
Sub test()
    Dim cl As Range, Data As Range, key$, item$, k
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    With Sheets("SheetName") 'specify Sheet Name
        Set Data = .Range("A2:Q" & .[A:A].Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row)
        Data.RemoveDuplicates Array(1, 9, 16, 17), xlYes
    End With

    For Each cl In Data.Columns(1).Cells
        key = cl.Value2
        item = cl.Offset(, 8).Value2 & "|" & cl.Offset(, 15).Value2 & "|" & cl.Offset(, 16).Value2
        If Not Dic.exists(key) Then
            Dic.Add key, item
        Else
            Dic(key) = Split(Dic(key), "|")(0) & ";" & Chr(10) & Split(item, "|")(0) & "|" & _
                       Split(Dic(key), "|")(1) & ";" & Chr(10) & Split(item, "|")(1) & "|" & _
                       Split(Dic(key), "|")(2) & ";" & Chr(10) & Split(item, "|")(2) & "|"

        End If
    Next cl

    Data.RemoveDuplicates (1), xlYes
    For Each k In Dic
        If Dic(k) Like "*;*" Then
            Set cl = Data.Columns(1).Find(k)
            With cl
                .Offset(, 8).Value2 = Split(Dic(k), "|")(0)
                .Offset(, 15).Value2 = Split(Dic(k), "|")(1)
                .Offset(, 16).Value2 = Split(Dic(k), "|")(2)
            End With
        End If
    Next k
End Sub
```

*before*:

[image]

*after*:

[image]